# ajax submit after html validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

im having a few problems with an ajax login form when i am clicking submit button its not validating the form before submitting the ajax its just submitting the form where am i going wrong

**this is the ajax script**

```js
    function wa_login() {
        var wa_username = $('#wa_username').val();
        var wa_password = $('#wa_password').val();
        var datas = 'wa_username=' + wa_username + '&wa_password=' + wa_password;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/limitless/functions.php',
            data: datas
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#info').html(data);
        });
    }
```

**here is the form itself**

```
<form class='form-horizontal form-validate-jquery' action='#' novalidate='novalidate'>
<div class='text-center'>
<div class='icon-object border-slate-300 text-slate-300'><i class='icon-reading'></i></div>
<h5 class='content-group'>Login to your account <small class='display-block'>Enter your credentials below</small></h5>
    </div>

<div class='form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left'>
<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Username' id='wa_username' required='required'>
 <div class='form-control-feedback'>
            <i class='icon-user text-muted'></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left'>
        <input type='password' class='form-control' placeholder='Password' id='wa_password' required='required'>
        <div class='form-control-feedback'>
            <i class='icon-lock2 text-muted'></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <button type='submit' onclick='wa_login()'   class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Sign in <i class='icon-circle-right2 position-right'></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class='text-center'>
        <a href='reset'>Forgot password?</a> | <a href='register' >Sign Up</a>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: It is not validating the form because you do not have any logic for form validation in your javascript function

Comment: The form submits because it is a submit button and submit buttons submit the form. Cancel the default action.

Comment: how do you stop the form from using its default action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is catch the form submit event with jQuery as follows:

```js
$('#form').on('submit',function(event){
  
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent default behavior
  
  if(formIsValid()){  // Execute validations in formIsValid() function
                      // returning true if valid, false if not
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/limitless/functions.php',
            data: $(this).serialize() // automatically serializing form
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#info').html(data);
    });
  } else{
    console.log('Sorry, wrong login credentials');
  }
  
  function formIsValid(){
    // Always returning false to show how submit is not called
    return false;
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Notice that an id is added to your form -->
<form id="form" class='form-horizontal form-validate-jquery' action='#' novalidate='novalidate'>
<div class='text-center'>
<div class='icon-object border-slate-300 text-slate-300'><i class='icon-reading'></i></div>
<h5 class='content-group'>Login to your account <small class='display-block'>Enter your credentials below</small></h5>
    </div>

<div class='form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left'>
<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Username' id='wa_username' required='required'>
 <div class='form-control-feedback'>
            <i class='icon-user text-muted'></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left'>
        <input type='password' class='form-control' placeholder='Password' id='wa_password' required='required'>
        <div class='form-control-feedback'>
            <i class='icon-lock2 text-muted'></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Sign in <i class='icon-circle-right2 position-right'></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class='text-center'>
        <a href='reset'>Forgot password?</a> | <a href='register' >Sign Up</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Watch the console log, you must see a message alerting about wrong login credentials.
Hope it helps!

Comment: the console gives me the error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @Nathan, you don't have jQuery properly installed or included.

Comment: just added the above code to a new html document and it still spams the error does the above code not include the jquery

Comment: @Nathan, if you invoke `$` before you've included jQuery, you will get this error.

Comment: fixed that the validation is working but doesn't look like its accessing the functions page

Comment: Sure, the error it is launching it's because wa_login it's not defined. You must delete the onclick event in the submit button. I'll edit the snippet to show you

Comment: Ready, check it out. Now you don't need the onclick event because it is attached via jQuery $('#form').on('submit', function(e){});

Comment: removed the onclick'' in the form still the same issue

Comment: snippet code doesnt work for me may need to remove novalidate='novalidate'

Comment: I'm running the code snippet and it doesn't throw any errors. What errors do you get?

Comment: ok couple of things were wrong for me in the test html file i had the java-script above the form this seems to matter it wouldn't work unless i put it at the end of the page. seems to be working for me now is there a way to return if the ajax completed successfully and redirect to another page?

Comment: it still doesnt to access functions.php but does spam console Sorry, wrong login credentials

Comment: Remember this is only an example. You have to customize somethings to work with your app. Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Change type button from `submit` to `button` then:

```
    function wa_login() {
        var wa_username = $('#wa_username').val();
        var wa_password = $('#wa_password').val();
        var datas = 'wa_username=' + wa_username + '&wa_password=' + wa_password;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/limitless/functions.php',
            data: datas
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#info').html(data);
            $("form").submit();
        });
    }
```

Comment: i have made the above change and the form still submits without validating first

Comment: did you change  to `type='button'` or just removed? Cuz the default is submit.

Comment: <button type='button' onclick='wa_login()'  and added $("form").submit(); to the ajax

Comment: Are you using the console or something to debug? Probably you have a JS error

Comment: Check out the answer below!

Comment: Ok, if you are clicking in the button and not pressing `enter` with focus on a field, that case @wilsotobianco approach would be a better one